# set SAML request for Office 365 Single Sign On

Tags: single-sign-on, microsoft-office-365

i am trying to set up single sign on for office 365 for my domain using my own identity provider. i have configured the domain to get to the login page of my identity provider whenever a user types in the credentials. though the login page of my identity provider opens, there is no **SAML Request** parameter in the URL of the page. is there some setting or configuration I need to do in order to send the correct SAML request?

i have followed these steps in configuring my domain:

1) add a new domain in office 365

2) add dns records and verify ownership

3) add user for that domain

4) set up ADFS (i have used Azure for this)

5) run Set-MsolDomainAuthentication  to convert the Office 365 domain from standard authentication to single sign-on

what else do i need to do?

Answer (score 0):

What is your idp running?

Have you seen http://blogs.office.com/2014/03/06/announcing-support-for-saml-2-0-federation-with-office-365/ . Please see implementers guide at http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9844221 for specific details for same idp. ADFS is not involved or required in this setup.

Take a fiddler trace to see how far you get.

Comment: i am not trying to use an existing IdP. i am trying with my own SAML based IdP